# flutter kernel_snapshot failed : Exception

Tags: flutter

/C:/Users/hanky/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_platform_widgets-2.2.6/lib/src/platform.dart:294:29: Error: The argument type 'bool?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'bool' because 'bool?' is nullable and 'bool' isn't.
semanticsDismissible: cupertino?.semanticsDismissible,
^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'D:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1201
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'D:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: please attach the code also

Comment: which code problem dont coming my code

Comment: I think in the debug console you can see the log, and in right side of the error, the file and line number is specified, you can head over to that code!

Comment: no bro this problem different i wrote the fail log.